# Angular - undefined to null field conversion

Tags: javascript, angular, null, undefined

I am developing an `angular` application with `spring` backend. I have a `FormGroup` as follows:

```
myForm = new FormGroup({
  fieldOne: new FormControl(),
  fieldTwo: new FormControl(),
  fieldThree: new FormControl()
});
```

that matches on object like this:

```
export class MyClass{
    firstField: number;
    secondField: number;
    thirdField: string;
}
```

When I submit the form I do something like this:

```
this.firstField = myForm.value.fieldOne;
```

The problem is that if the fields are not set, they are `undefined`. This is causing problem to the backend service that cannot deserialize the object because it doesn't expects `undefined` but `null`.

This could solve my problem:

```
this.firstField = myForm.value.fieldOne ? myForm.value.fieldOne : null;
```

but when I have a lot of fields it's really not that elegant.
Then I found the following works:

```
export class MyClass{
    firstField: number = null;
    secondField: number = null;
    thirdField: string = null;
}
```

It would be perfect. My question is, since I'm new to `javascript`: is that correct? Is there another best practice to do this kind of conversion? How do you usually solve this kind of serialization problems between frontend and backend? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Manu has pointed out you can assign null values. And also you can define default values as well. Just like follows

```
export class MyClass{
    firstField: number = 0;
    secondField: number = 0;
    thirdField: string = '';
}
```

So here you don't need to handle `undefined` or `null` value. And this is good practice to initialize values like this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any issue with your approach. Its the default behaviour to get undefined for form values that are not set; as per the definition:

> The undefined property indicates that a variable has not been assigned
>   a value.

When you assign `null` as default value then since JavaScript null is "nothing". It is supposed to be something that doesn't exist. So go ahead with assigning all member variables as null if backend can't handle undefined.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a cleaner solution you could make an init function inside your class that will initialize all your values to `null` like:

```
export class MyClass{
    firstField: number;
    secondField: number;
    thirdField: string;

    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }

    private init(): void {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).forEach(
            (property) => {
                this[property] = null;
            }
        );


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set every field value to null in case they are undefined:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.firstField  = myForm.value.fieldOne;
obj.secondField = myForm.value.fieldTwo;
//...
Object.keys(obj).forEach(field => obj[field] = obj[field] || null);
```